# Dynamic population of url in http:outbound-gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Dynamic population of url in http:outbound-gateway giving error

tried below code

```
 <int:header-enricher input-channel="jmsInboundChannel_POST" output-channel="outbound_gateway_channel_POST">
        <int:header name="postURL" expression="payload.getUrl()"/>
        <int:header name="Accept-Language" value="en_GB"/>
        <int:header name="X-Source-CountryCode" value="GB"/>
        <int:header name="X-Source-Operator" value="Enterprise"/>
        <int:header name="X-Source-Division" value="OrderManagement"/>
        <int:header name="X-Source-System" value="${sapwebservices.http.header.source.system}"/>
        <int:header name="X-Source-Timestamp" expression="new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(new java.util.Date())"/>
        <int:header name="Accept" value="application/json"/>
        <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int:object-to-json-transformer input-channel="outbound_gateway_channel_POST"
            output-channel="create_order_outbound_gateway_with_json_POST"
            object-mapper="nonNullObjectMapper"/>
    <http:outbound-gateway
            mapped-request-headers="Accept*, Content-Type, X-*, HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS"
            request-channel="create_order_outbound_gateway_with_json_POST"
            reply-channel="print_payload"
            url="${UrlVariable}"
            http-method="POST"
            expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
            charset="UTF-8"
            request-factory="httpRequestFactory">
        <http:uri-variable name="UrlVariable" expression="headers['postURL']"/>
    </http:outbound-gateway>
```

giving error

```
org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler#1' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'UrlVariable' in string value "${UrlVariable}"
```

I'm using spring-integration-http-2.1 jar.

Trying to dynamically populate the url for every request.

@Gary, tried your solution, getting below exception.

```
WARN  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-6] [GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway] failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [{urlVariable}]
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:284)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:114)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:61)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    ......
    ......
    ......
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:463)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:355)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1069)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1061)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:958)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:139)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:456)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    ... 86 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `url="${UrlVariable}"`

Remove the `$`; placeholders here are just `{....}`.

`${...}` placeholders are evaluated once, during context initialization.

Comment: That's a different problem to the original question; I am not familiar with `BasicClientConnectionManager`; I suggest you ask a new question with an appropriate subject line.